# Openshift deploy angular application

Tags: node.js, openshift

I am trying to deploy an agular application in openshift.

I am using nodesjs s2i image, with the git source. https://github.com/kaushik9845/angularopenshift.git

I have used custom assemble script as below lines were making the build fail with reason 
---> Cleaning up npm cache
rm: cannot remove '.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/0b/61': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/10/7d': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/19/2f': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '.npm/_cacache/index-v5/07/1c': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '.npm/_cacache/index-v5/37/5c': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '.npm/_cacache/index-v5/99/a0': Directory not empty

```
echo "---> Cleaning up npm cache"
rm -rf .npm
```

So skipping that line in the custom assemble script.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Custom assembling"


echo "---> Installing application source"
cp -Rfp /tmp/src/. ./
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set loglevel warn
npm install
ng build --prod --base-href /mybuild/
fix-permissions /opt/app-root

exit 0
```

But it is failing with the below error

```
Error: Cannot find module '/opt/app-root/src/server.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
```

Comment: Since we use ng serve to run in local ..I even used ng serve in package.json under scripts.start. But  it gives me a red warning This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!

Comment: Is there a way to combine nodejs s2i image with docker images like apache/nginx

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check out this [blog post](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/23/modern-web-applications-on-openshift-part-2-using-chained-builds/),  it talks about using a "chained build", where you are using a Node.js image to build your application, then passing those "built" artifacts to an Nginx image to serve